# How to use ApplicationRunner in scala?

Tags: scala, spring-boot

I am trying to initialize a database using ApplicationRunner , my springboot application is writen in scala

```
def applicationRunner(facilityRepository: FacilityRepository): ApplicationRunner = args => { 

    facilityRepository.save(new Facility("Facility1", "Facility1Desc"))
    facilityRepository.save(new Facility("Facility2", "Facility2Desc")) 

}
```

I am getting a "missing parameter type" error when i compile, what is missing in my code

I am using CrudRepository for CRUD operation

Comment: Can you show `FacilityRepository`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik

trait FacilityRepository extends CrudRepository[Facility, Int] {

}

Comment: Can you try to change `args =>` to `args: ApplicationArguments =>` ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik  - i changed my approach, i use "extends ApplicationRunner" and override the "run" method